# Json_encode returns string in parts

Tags: json

I have a php array wich looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => rgb(255, 126, 28) [1] => rgb(255, 126, 28) [2] => rgb(255, 126, 28)...
```

And I want to pass it through jason_encode, but the problem is that it's only returning the first character of the elements. And if try to encode only the frist element of the array, it returns all the characters in it one by one.

Here is my jason_encode script:

```
    var arrayFromPHP = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>

$.each(arrayFromPHP, function (i, elem) {
    alert(elem.value);
});
```

Could you help me fix this?
Thanks in advance!